# JBoss 7 Maximum HttpSession

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jboss7.x

We are using JBoss 7.1.1 in the production server, few of the user http session is lost during peak hours. Any limitation in the http session in this Jboss version, we are unable reproduce this issue in the testing environment.

JBoss will clear the inactive sessions or once the limit is reached?

Debug log

> 18:31:19,239 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl]
>   (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) Removing
>   session wGGx4QGwc0Hs9XmNeAfMQbCo from principal's set of registered
>   sessions

Please help